# Retrieving specific entries in Nested Lists

Tags: python, list, position, nested

I'm new to Python and programming in general, so I apologise if I am not doing things in the most efficient manner possible.

Suppose I have a list:

```
Coords = [[1, 1], [2, 1], [1, 2], [1, 1]]
```

And I'd like to make a new list called xCoords:

```
xCoords = [1, 2, 1, 1]
```

How may I go about doing this?
I'd like a method which is expandable, as the problem I am currently working on involves an arbitrarily long list of positions.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple way would be with a list comprehension

```
xCoords = [i[0] for i in Coords]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could [transpose](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) the list with `zip`, and then select the first row with simple indexing:

```
>>> Coords = [[1, 1], [2, 1], [1, 2], [1, 1]]
>>> zip(*Coords)
[(1, 2, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2, 1)]
>>> zip(*Coords)[0]
(1, 2, 1, 1)
>>> list(zip(*Coords)[0])
[1, 2, 1, 1]
```

This is somewhat more memory intensive than a list comprehension approach, however.